# Deleting column in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a huge list, ex. {a,b,c},{d,e,f} and I must have only {a,c},{d,f}. I using import from url.
My sentence:

```
Drop[Import["url"],{2}]
```

And it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: why do you need the `Import[]`? You can use only the list as argument. Also, look at the manual for `Drop`: it says it deletes the first n elements. If you use `Drop[yourlist,2]` you will be deleting the first 2 elements of `yourlist`. Have a look into `Delete[]`, maybe this is what you want

Comment: You could also try importing just the columns of interest.  For example: `Import["URL", {"Data", {All}, {1, 3}}];` (See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5921/106))

Comment: Please consider using the dedicated SE site for *Mathematica*: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the third parameter of the `Drop` function, like so:

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
Drop[list, None, {2}]
```

This will return:

```
{{a, c}, {d, f}}
```

Comment: Things you learn. I never noticed a third parameter in `Drop`, +1.

Comment: This is not only a third parameter: if your list is deeper, you can use as many parameters as dimensions in it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to map drop over the list.

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
Map[Drop[#, {2}] &, list]
```

> {{a, c}, {d, f}}

Alternatively, use transpose, but this is apparently less efficient because it makes copies of the list.

```
Transpose@Drop[Transpose@list, {2}]
```